# Clarification on Default SageMaker Distribution Strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

**Context**: When using SageMaker distributed training: Let’s say when training a network I do not provide any distribution parameter (keep it to default), but provide 2 instances for the `instance_count` value in the estimator (could be any deep learning based estimator, e.g., PyTorch).

In this scenario would there be any distributed training taking place? If so, what strategy is used by default?

**NOTE**: I could see both instances’ GPUs are actively used but wondering what sort of distributed training take place by default ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using custom code (custom Docker, custom code in Framework container) The answer is **NO**. Unless you are writing distributed code (Horovod, PyTorch DDP, MPI...), SageMaker will not distribute things for you. It will launch the same Docker or Python code N times, once per instance. Consider SageMaker Training API like a whiteboard, that can create multiple connected and configured machines for you. But the code is still yours to write. [SageMaker Distributed Training Libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/distributed-training.html) can make distributed code much easier to write though.
- If you're using a built-in algorithm, the answer is **it depends**. Some SageMaker built-in algorithms natively are multi-machine, like SM XGBoost or SM Random Cut Forest.